# apply video settings for specific monitor model

Tags: display

How can i change the display settings when using a specific monitor model?

I frequently use my raspberry pi with different models of monitors, and at home i use a vertical widescreen monitor. i want to rotate the display 90 degrees, but only when using a specific monitor model.

The monitor can be identified using the [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data), How can i apply the display settings to a specific EDID?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do what you want during boot (config.txt doesn't seem to have a way of configuring by EDID).

Perhaps you could use the tvservice utility (tvservice --help).

Interrogate the display (tvservice --name) and then set the correct mode accordingly (tvservice --explicit ...).